# Calculating F1 score, precision, recall in tfhub retraining script

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow hub for image retraining classification task. The tensorflow script [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) by default calculates cross_entropy and accuracy.

```
train_accuracy, cross_entropy_value = sess.run([evaluation_step, cross_entropy],feed_dict={bottleneck_input: train_bottlenecks, ground_truth_input: train_ground_truth})
```

I would like to get F1 score, precision, recall and confusion matrix. How could I get these values using this script ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below I include a method to calculate desired metrics using *scikit-learn* package.

You can calculate F1 score, precision and recall using [precision_recall_fscore_support](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html) method and the confusion matrix using [confusion_matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) method:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support, confusion_matrix
```

Both methods take two 1D array-like objects which store ground truth and predicted labels respectively.

In the code provided, ground-truth labels for training data are stored in `train_ground_truth` variable which is defined in lines [1054](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L1054) and [1060](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L1060), while `validation_ground_truth` stores ground-truth labels for validation data and is defined in line [1087](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L1087).

The tensor that calculates predicted class labels is defined and returned by [add_evaluation_step](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L804) function. You can modify line [1034](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L1034) in order to capture that tensor object:

```
evaluation_step, prediction = add_evaluation_step(final_tensor, ground_truth_input)
# now prediction stores the tensor object that 
# calculates predicted class labels
```

Now you can update line [1076](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L1076) in order to evaluate `prediction` when calling `sess.run()`:

```
train_accuracy, cross_entropy_value, train_predictions = sess.run(
    [evaluation_step, cross_entropy, prediction],
    feed_dict={bottleneck_input: train_bottlenecks,
               ground_truth_input: train_ground_truth})

# train_predictions now stores class labels predicted by model

# calculate precision, recall and F1 score
(train_precision,
 train_recall,
 train_f1_score, _) = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true=train_ground_truth,
                                                      y_pred=train_predictions,
                                                      average='micro')
# calculate confusion matrix
train_confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true=train_ground_truth,
                                          y_pred=train_predictions)
```

Similarly, you can compute metrics for validation subset by modifying line [1095](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L1095):

```
validation_summary, validation_accuracy, validation_predictions = sess.run(
    [merged, evaluation_step, prediction],
    feed_dict={bottleneck_input: validation_bottlenecks,
               ground_truth_input: validation_ground_truth})

# validation_predictions now stores class labels predicted by model

# calculate precision, recall and F1 score
(validation_precision,
 validation_recall,
 validation_f1_score, _) = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true=validation_ground_truth,
                                                           y_pred=validation_predictions,
                                                           average='micro')
# calculate confusion matrix
validation_confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true=validation_ground_truth,
                                               y_pred=validation_predictions)
```

Finally, the code calls [run_final_eval](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L825) to evaluate trained model on test data. In this function, `prediction` and `test_ground_truth` are already defined, so you only need to include code to calculate required metrics:

```
test_accuracy, predictions = eval_session.run(
    [evaluation_step, prediction],
    feed_dict={
        bottleneck_input: test_bottlenecks,
        ground_truth_input: test_ground_truth
    })

# calculate precision, recall and F1 score
(test_precision,
 test_recall,
 test_f1_score, _) = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true=test_ground_truth,
                                                     y_pred=predictions,
                                                     average='micro')
# calculate confusion matrix
test_confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true=test_ground_truth,
                                         y_pred=predictions)
```

Note that the provided code calculates *global* F1-scores by setting `average='micro'`. The different averaging methods that are supported by scikit-learn package are described in [User Guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-classification).